# Как сделать чтобы iframe сразу не загружался?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Как сделать чтобы iframe сразу не загружался?

Я его пытаюсь скрывать через стиль css : `display: none;`
B через JS его востанавливаю по нажатию на кнопку. 
Но не смотря на это, он все равно загружается.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нужно просто устанавливать атрибут `src` для элемента `<iframe>` по клику:

```js
(function () {


  var button = document.querySelector('button');
  var iframe = document.querySelector('iframe');


  button.addEventListener('click', function () {
  
    iframe.src = iframe.getAttribute('data-src');

    iframe.classList.toggle('hidden');

  });


})();
```

```css
iframe {
  display: block;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<button>Show iframe</button>

<iframe class="hidden" data-src="//w3.org"></iframe>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jrrjatt7/

---

[Навеяло](https://webref.ru/html/iframe#comment-2698204232) ещё вариант без JS, который может пригодиться:

```css
iframe {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<a href="//w3.org" target="w3">

  <button>Show iframe</button>

</a>

<iframe name="w3"></iframe>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/am2fgqrp/

Однако у него два минуса. Правда эти минусы косвенны, так как, как вы понимаете, всё зависит от того, что мы хотим реализовать:

1. `iframe` нельзя скрыть изначально.
2. После второго клика по кнопке-ссылке `iframe` не скрывается, а просто загружается заново.

---

Можно было бы, конечно, поизвращаться с `input type="checkbox"` и `label`, чтобы реализовать такой же функционал, как и при использовании JS, но `label` и `a` не совместимы (смотрите комментарий [здесь](https://webref.ru/html/label#comment-2698584775)); да и не стоит это того: JS — наше всё!